# Databricks DBT Runtime Error, cannot connect to Database. Maybe an SSL error?

Tags: apache-spark, ssl-certificate, database-connection, databricks, dbt

I have a custom Databricks instance with a Domain name that points to an AWS Load Balancer. When I put that information in using either the HTTP instructions [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/warehouse-profiles/spark-profile) or the databricks cluster instructions [here](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/dbt.html), I get this response in the DBT CLI:

```
Connection:
host: https://subdomain.domain.com
  port: 443
  cluster: 123456-stuff00003
  endpoint: None
  schema: default
  organization: 0
16:40:39.470091 [debug] [MainThread]: Acquiring new spark connection "debug"
16:40:39.471632 [debug] [MainThread]: Using spark connection "debug"
16:40:39.472524 [debug] [MainThread]: On debug: select 1 as id
16:40:39.472953 [debug] [MainThread]: Opening a new connection, currently in state init
  Connection test: [ERROR]

1 check failed:
dbt was unable to connect to the specified database.
The database returned the following error:

  >Runtime Error
  Database Error
    failed to connect
```

Unfortunately, DBT's debugging logs are terrible and I am not entirely sure why it is failing. I do know that when I connect to the cluster via Intellij I have to provide the `CA file`, the `Client Certificate file`, and the `Client key file`, because I am using a self-signed SSL cert (unfortunately, the self signed cert is required). Also, when defining my `~/.databrickscfg` file I have to provide the argument `insecure = true`.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this issue recently and I fixed it by installing root certificates by executing the "Install Certificates.command" script in the python home directory used to run dbt.

Laurent

Comment: Hi @Laurent How do I do this?

Comment: On MacOs, go to Applications, expand Python application folder, and execute "Install Certificates.command" script ... and that's it.